# pom.xml maven properties in leiningen project.clj

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen, clojure-java-interop

I use the `$ lein pom` command to genereate a maven `pom.xml` from a Leiningen `project.clj` file. I do that because I have Java source files in my Clojure project.

I would like to make sure the following maven properties are embedded into the generated `pom.xml` file:

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I do this by hand now. However, I do not want to check in the generated file into version control and I would like to be able to regenerate it any time. How can I make Leiningen to embed the maven properties in the generated `pom.xml` file every time I generate the `pom.xml`?

Thank you

Comment: Why you don't want to compile Java with lein as well?

Comment: i use lein to compile java. but it turned out my java IDE only supports maven projects not lein projects, so i generate a pom.xml before opening the project in the editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add custom `pom.xml` entries using [`:pom-addition`](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/135724235b1a963a806e24d036326a1bddeced1a/sample.project.clj#L502-L512):

```
(defproject ...
  ...
  :pom-addition [:properties
                  ["maven.compiler.source" "1.7"]
                  ["maven.compiler.target" "1.7"]])
```